# Docker container knows rbenv global but not ruby

Tags: ruby, docker, rbenv

When running my docker container it knows rbenv global. But when ever it try to find ruby via `ruby` or `which ruby` or `whereis ruby` I get nothing. It also doesn't recognize `rails-api` or `gem`. What is going on?

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM centos:6.6

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install git openssl-devel openssh-server sudo openssl readline-devel readline zlib-devel zlib libxml2-devel libxml2 libxslt-devel libxslt nginx tar gcc libaio libaio-devel -y
RUN rpm -Uvh https://opscode-omnibus-packages.s3.amazonaws.com/el/6/x86_64/chef-12.5.1-1.el6.x86_64.rpm
RUN sed -i -e "s/Defaults    requiretty.*/ #Defaults    requiretty/g" /etc/sudoers

RUN mkdir -p /var/run/sshd

RUN useradd -m -u 1000 -G wheel deploy && echo '%wheel  ALL=(ALL)  NOPASSWD: ALL' >> /etc/sudoers.d/wheel
USER deploy
RUN mkdir ~/dev

RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv/
RUN git clone https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build

ENV PATH ~/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
RUN echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN source ~/.bash_profile
ENV CONFIGURE_OPTS --disable-install-doc

RUN rbenv install 2.2.3
RUN rbenv global 2.2.3
RUN bash -l -c 'gem update --system'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem update'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries'
RUN bash -l -c 'gem install bundler rails-api --no-rdoc --no-ri'

COPY oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
COPY oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
COPY oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm

RUN sudo rpm -Uvh /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
RUN sudo rpm -Uvh /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
RUN sudo rpm -Uvh /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm

RUN sudo touch /etc/sysconfig/network

RUN NLS_LANG=American_America.UTF8
ENV ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.1/client64/lib

EXPOSE 22
EXPOSE 3000
EXPOSE 5000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue at hand here is that every `RUN` statement in the `Dockerfile` happens in its own environment. The `RUN source ~/.bash_profile` will set `$PATH` to have `/root/.rbenv/shims` in it. But subsequent `RUN` will not have this environment set as they won't source `.bash_profile` since this isn't an interactive shell.

The easy way to solve this is to just add a `ENV PATH $HOME/.rbenv/bin:$HOME/.rbenv/shims:$PATH` somewhere before the `ruby` and `gem` commands. This is really the only bit you should need from the `rbenv` init shell script.

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't immediately source bash_profile when I start the container?

Comment: Because `.bash_profile` is for interactive shells. You are looking for `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `rbenv rehash` after installing the new Ruby version?

Answer (score 1):

Your Dockerfile only uses one version of Ruby. Given your use case, I would recommend just using the official ruby docker images: https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby